# Convergence in $L_1$ with different norms

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I saw an example proving that a sequence that converges in $||.||_2$ doesn't necessarily have to converge in $||.||_1$. However, I was wondering if a sequence converges in $||.||_1$, does it converge to the same point? I couldn't really figure out if there were any counter examples to this claim. So, I was just wondering.

Comment: Are you working over some specific space? There are conditions, measure-wise to determine if ||.||_p convergence imolies ||.||_q convergence.

Comment: I am just working over metric spaces @MSIS.

Answer (score 2):

So you are wondering if $\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{2}}\rightarrow 0$ and $\|f_{n}-g\|_{L^{1}}\rightarrow 0$ imply that $f=g$?

The answer is affirmative. Note that $\int|f_{n}-f|^{2}d\mu\rightarrow 0$ implies $|f_{n_{k}}(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow 0$ $\mu$-a.e. for a subsequence.

Subsequently, $\int|f_{n_{k}}-g|d\mu\rightarrow 0$, and so $|f_{n_{k_{l}}}(x)-g(x)|\rightarrow 0$ $\mu$-a.e. for a further subsequence.

Now note that $|f(x)-g(x)|\leq|f_{n_{k_{l}}}(x)-f(x)|+|f_{n_{k_{l}}}(x)-g(x)|$ for all such $x$.